Soft Actor Critic policy update depending on q function in discrete action space
Reference: https://spinningup.openai.com/en/latest/algorithms/sac.html
In the psuedo-code of the algorithm, line 14, the actor update is written as to maximize the q-function. Theoretically, this means that the policy should navigate the q-function in order to maximize it.
Assume we only have two actions to take, a1 = [1, 0] and a2 = [0, 1]. Q(a1) < Q(a2). Suppose that the Q-function is a neural network that's trained to optimality.
In the action space, let the line joining a1 and a2 be (d)
to maximize the q function, the policy should move from taking a1 to taking a2. This "movement" is ensured by the Gumbel-Softmax trick, allowing us to differentiate the policy outputs despite them being categorical. This will happen by (roughly) moving along the line (d). The Q-function has no knowledge of the line (d) as it is only trained on actions that are one-hot encoded. It never and will never train on something like [0.2, 0.5]. As this vector is not in the action space.
After weeks of trying to train a model, I think this is my problem. In practice, the result is that Q function evaluates perfectly, yet the policy is equivalent in reward to a random policy.

I tried Joint-training and it didn't work. Q function great, policy very bad.
I tried to train the Q function first as a supervised problem (I have a way to obtain perfect Q values). Then train the policy. Q function great, policy very bad.

RL is not my field. So I might have missed something. If my analysis is correct, is there any way to address the problem?
